# The cardinality of $n_1,n_2,n_3$ such that $n_1 < n_2< n_3$ and $1 \leq n_i \leq 10$ is $\binom{10}{3}$ explanation.

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose you have $10$ balls with numbers on them, ranging from $1$ to $10$ (there are no two balls with same number). We pick three of them consecutively and put them back, and we want to know what is the probability of getting three balls with numbers strictly increasing.

Now, at the beginning I was reasonning just as the author of the correction: there are $\binom{10}{3}$ choices the end result. There is only one way to arrange them in a strictly increasing way.

Now this is where I have a hard time to understand:

> "there is exactly the same number of ways of arranging $3$ balls in an strictly increasing order (that are numbered from $1$ to $10$) as there are ways to arrange $3$ elements from $10$ elements, to be precise: $\binom{10}{3}$ "

This is what I fail to understand. Why is this so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

${m}\choose{r}$ means the number of *sets of $r$ (different) things* that can be chosen from $m$ things as distinct from the number of *ordered $r$-tuples with all elements different*.

There are $r!$ different ways of ordering a set of $r$ things, so the latter is $r!$ times the former.

If you have a linear order $<$ on the $m$ things, then there is exactly one $n$-tuple that can be formed from any subset of size $r$ that satisfies $n_1<n_2<...<n_r$. (The smallest has to go first, the smallest from the remainder next and so on.) So there are exactly the same number of ordered $r$-tuples satisfying the condition as sets of size $r$.

This is really saying much the same as what you quoted. If it still doesn't make sense, try it with say four cards marked 1 to 4 and making ascending sequences of three cards.